# QGIS Neighbor Code Incorrect? Find Neighboring Districts?

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS/Python and am trying to analyze neighboring district attributes using QGIS. I downloaded this code for identifying neighbors:

http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/find_neighbor_polygons.html

When I run the python code and look at the results, the list of neighbors looks inaccurate. For instance, my attribute table says that the Krishna district in India has no neighbors but one of the Nalgonda district's neighbors is Krishna. This makes no sense to me. Does anyone have any insights?

How do I find a district's neighbors in QGIS, since the code from the website doesn't seem to be working for me?

Thank you.

Edited to Add: I'm new to QGIS so I'm not entirely sure what information to add. If this question is unclear, please let me know what other details would help make it more clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code was fine. Several districts in India are either non-contiguous or islands, which is why they had different neighbors/no neighbors.